# Isn't answer duplicating a little overly strict if the intend is to help people who are looking for solutions, find the easiest way?

Tags: discussion

I have posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662836/using-customparameter-with-visual-studio-multi-project-template/53973072?noredirect=1#comment94785600_53973072), to make people who are looking into resolving their issue which landed there through google, find an easy solution to their problem.

I think dropping the same answer on 2 questions, isn't that excessive that it justifies deleting an answer, which would have helped someone who has this issue.

**Am i alone with that thought?**

if it was 5+ questions, ok - whatever. But that was literally the two questions which helped me most, building that tool.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Er, yes, no, that's too much, please don't do that. Having to follow all of one link to read the answer is really not that much to ask of a human.

Comment: "Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked" was the advice given by the moderator. Were the questions different? Then the answer can be made to better fit each one. Were the questions the same? Then they should have been flagged as duplicates. You haven't addressed that counsel by the moderator at all in your question, instead you started talking about how excessive it is to delete identical posted answers. Please clarify your question with why the existing moderator's comment does not answer your concern as to why duplicate answers aren't allowed.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier is what you are trying to say the correct thing would be placing the answer in one place, and referencing to that answer from another question?

Comment: @Dbl if the two questions have the same answer, they're probably duplicates. Flag as such.

Comment: As for deleting an answer - most likely it was not deleted for being duplicate but for being basically a link-only answer...

Answer (score 21):

> I think dropping the same answer on 2 questions, isn't that excessive that it justifies deleting an answer, which would have helped someone who has this issue.

Anything *might* help someone. I once answered a question by posting 32 copies of a waffle recipe - that *might've* helped someone who, while researching the question was suddenly overtaken by an irrepressible desire for waffles. But that's unlikely, and so the answers are all deleted.

In your case, you answered a question asking for help passing information from a multi-project template through to child templates... With the following text:

> I got fed up with maintaining vstemplate files so i made this:
>
> https://github.com/taori/Amusoft.VisualStudio.TemplateGenerator
>
> It allows you to create template configurations, reference a solution file, specify output folders, configure image/name etc and does everything else for you. That way you can just modify the solution whenever you want to change it and easily rebuild the result. Without having to tediously manipulate and prepare files.

Now, that could very well be helpful to someone looking for help creating template configurations, referencing solution files, specifying output folders, configuring image/name etc. And perhaps someone reading this question will be overtaken by an irrepressible desire to do one of those things, just as a hypothetical reader of my answers might put aside their original research to make waffles. **But that's still unlikely.**

Unlike many similar forums, we have an important rule for authors here at Stack Overflow: [Answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

You don't have to hand them a solution on a silver platter, but you should at least try to acknowledge that you understood the problem and that the information you're presenting can help. Ignoring it entirely (or hand-waving specifics with "does everything") is rude at best, and... Well, at worst [it'll cause folks to suspect you're just spamming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> - Don't tell - show! The best way to avoid being seen as a snake-oil salesman is to demonstrate a solution rather than simply asserting the problem can be solved.
> - Always solve the asker's problem. A good answer should at minimum allow the person whose question you're answering to solve their problem. Not all questions can be answered this way, but if you don't think you can write up a complete solution then you're better off looking for a different question.

As it stands, your answer was posted to a question that already had two good, useful, *specific* answers - one recommending a tool, another a built-in method of solving the specific problem. You should at minimum explain why your answer was needed at all, and then provide specifics as to how it solved the problem - if you can't do that, you might as well have just written about waffles.

Comment: Hmmmm.. waffles. Brb.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if it's a duplicate it is a duplicate, so the mods delete it because little to similar and may well be because it is kinda left alone, and down-voted, and doesn't really receive enough attention, so it's basically abandoned and left alone, so why not delete it?

I seem to agree with the moderator for doing this.

Comment: it is similar to the answer of another question - not similar to another answer within the same question. that however is ignored a lot on SO and fills the place with actually useless content.

Comment: @Dbl: It isn't "similar" to anything; it's the *same answer*. Whether it's 2 times or twenty, you shouldn't repost the same answer on different questions. If the questions can be answered by verbatim identical answers, then the questions are probably duplicates.

Comment: @NicolBolas I still think of it as telling someone that he can use the boat to get to england, ignoring that he asks "how can i swim to england from denmark?", still left him better off in the long run.